# Python Django DRF API one time session/token/pass authentication without a username/password

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework, one-time-password

I have a Django and django rest framework project where I want a mobile to be able to request a token and then use that token for x minutes before they're disconnected. I do not want to create a user for each mobile device, I just want a one time password.

I tried using the auth system built into drf, however it required a user.

So I was thinking about just using the onetimepass package to generate a one time token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a view that generates a time-based OTP and then use it in a custom auth module to authenticate against a single user. You can also use JWT with an expiry time to authenticate against a single user.